# How can I mount vxfs FS to two or more Solaris servers?

Tags: solaris, storage, cluster, shared-disk

I want to have two Solaris servers share the same SAN vxfs Filesystem. Though at a time just one would be accessing the share. This is to allow for a quick failover in case the primary server undergoes an unplanned outage for some reason.

From the [Oracle Solaris Cluster Software Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19680-01/html/821-1255/toc.html), it seems a cluster needs to be setup and VxVM Software needs to be running on both servers to manage the cluster - which seems quite complicated in comparison to simply mounting a NAS share on two or more servers, for creating a shared filesystem.

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing what Solaris Cluster does vs. Oracle RAC.

In Solaris Cluster (SunCluster) any application running is actually running on a single node in the cluster rather then on multiple ones.  Which means that Veritas Volume Manager imports the associated Volume Group only on one of the nodes in the cluster.

So there is no issue with it.  If you are looking to run the group in Parallel on multiple nodes in the cluster you will need to make sure that you're running [VxCFS](http://www.symantec.com/cluster-file-system), which provides Veritas Cluster Volume Manager that are required to handle locking and synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Solaris Cluster, formerly Sun Cluster, can mount UFS or VxFS filesystems in parallel on any number of nodes in the cluster.   Veritas also has a Cluster Manager that can accomplish similar functionality, via VxCFS, as mentioned by Karlson.

First, add your VxFS to every `/etc/vfstab` on every node in the cluster:

```
/dev/vx/dsk/dg1/v1 /dev/vx/rdsk/dg1/v1 /global/v1 vxfs 5 yes log,global
```

I'm going to assume you already have a resource group for this, called `gfs`, and you've already registered the `HAStoragePlus` resource type, via `clrt register HAStoragePlus`.

Now you just create the resource for your global fs:

```
clrs create -g gfs -t HAStoragePlus -p FileSystemMountPoints="/global/v1" v1-rs
```

And, enable the resource group:

```
clrg online -M gfs
```

There are a lot of other steps necessary to get a cluster up and running, so I'm assuming a certain baseline of knowledge of Solaris Cluster.